# Need CSS Help with a hover element - cant extend to left and right of page

Tags: css

Need some CSS guru help. If you visit my link:

http://www.gabbr.com/js/viewer/cmedata/index1.html

and hover over the years (top middles, 2008, 2009, 2010, etc) you will notice an orange bar extending from the top to the bottom of the page. I am trying to get the same effect on the left (month and day) but am unable to do so.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the orange hover bar to extend off the left of the screen for either #dayleft or for #monthleft. It extends all the way to the right margin of the screen but not the left. The problem is the margin-left: 15px; in #monthleft and margin-left: 80px; in #dayleft. But I cannot get rid of these since I require them for the letter spacing.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

```
#monthleft ul li a:hover {
   margin-left: -20px;
   width: 110%;
   text-indent: 20px;
}
```

Add this to your hover code. This did the trick for me in firebug.

Apply the same principle for your #dayleft element, adjusting the measurements of margin-left and text-indent to suit.

**EDIT:** This works for #dayleft

```
#dayleft ul li a:hover {
   margin-left: -110px;
   width: 110%;
   text-indent: 110px;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the way to do it. Depending on what you'll use this effect for, an alternative would be to rethink the structure and create parent elements to which the hover is applied. In other words, you first create a grid to which the hover is applied and then place text inside it.

Comment: I agree with Tom on the new structural idea. Not to mention depending on the use of what you wish the navigation to achieve, whenever that page is filled with Years and Dates, it will be hard to navigate. 

Unless you are doing the whole X + Y date selection? If that is the case, then props to you! Awesome stuff.

Comment: (tip) windows IE might render it with scroll bars for the X axis... test it and if so, use overflow:hidden; on the above code :)